# Find paths from a graph and then count how many times a path occurs in Azure Cosmos DB using Gremlin

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am storing clickstream events in graph database using the below structure
[image]

User perform multiple events and each event has a edge towards previous event:

- Vertices are 'user' and 'event'
- Edges are 'performed' and 'previous'

Each event has a property named referer.
For eg, if a user views a page www.foobar.com/aaa
then there will be a page view event and it will have referer:www.foobar.com/aaa

Now I want to find the possible paths from homepage with their count

Using the below Gremlin query I am able to find the possible paths, but I am not able to group them to find counts of each path:

```
g.V().hasLabel('event').has('referer','https://www.foobar.com/').in('previous').in('previous').path().by('referer')
```

Output:

```
 [
      {
        "labels": [
          [],
          [],
          []
        ],
        "objects": [
          "https://www.foobar.com/",
          "https://www.foobar.com/aaa",
          "https://www.foobar.com/bbb"
        ]
      },
      {
        "labels": [
          [],
          [],
          []
        ],
        "objects": [
          "https://www.foobar.com/",
          "https://www.foobar.com/aaa",
          "https://www.foobar.com/bbb"
        ]
      },
      {
        "labels": [
          [],
          [],
          []
        ],
        "objects": [
          "https://www.foobar.com/",
          "https://www.foobar.com/ccc",
          "https://www.foobar.com/ddd"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I want an output like this:

```
[[
  "https://www.foobar.com/",
  "https://www.foobar.com/aaa",
  "https://www.foobar.com/bbb"
]:2,
[
  "https://www.foobar.com/",
  "https://www.foobar.com/ccc",
  "https://www.foobar.com/ddd"
]:1]
```

Since I am using azure cosmos graph db only these gremlin operators are available
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support
Thanks

Comment: You can apply `groupCount` to a path using a syntax such as this:

`groupCount().by(path().by('referer'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `groupCount` to a `path` using a syntax such as this:

```
groupCount().by(path().by('referer'))
```

So you could rewrite your query as:

```
g.V().hasLabel('event').
      has('referer','https://www.foobar.com/').
      in('previous').
      in('previous').
      groupCount().by(path().by('referer'))
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers
Kelvin

Comment: Thanks @Kelvin. It is giving  'Cannot resolve object to a primitive value'. exception. think it cannot group by on array as path().by('referer') gives an array. May be it will require string concatenation of referers and then group by. Do you have any idea on how to do that ? thanks

Comment: I tested the query both locally using a TinkerGraph and remotely to a GremlinServer connected to JanusGraph using my air-routes graph and it worked fine. So I think the overall syntax/pattern of the query is OK. There may be something I am missing or maybe some aspect of Cosmos that is causing it to fail.

Comment: I also tried with TInkerGraph and it works, may be some problem with cosmos's gremlin implementation. For now I am keeping this question open, if I don't get any other solution I will mark this as answer. thanks